# Node.js and sha1

Tags: php, node.js, cryptography, base64, sha1

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php

```
string sha1 ( string $str [, bool $raw_output = false ] )
```

If the optional raw_output is set to TRUE, then the sha1 digest is instead returned in raw binary format with a length of 20, otherwise the returned value is a 40-character hexadecimal number.

---

```
crypto = require("crypto");
console.log( new Buffer(crypto.createHash('sha1').update("some text").digest()).toString('base64') );
// N8KqY8OHc8KYw5lURzJiw6HCoAV8HmMuw5p3
console.log( new Buffer(crypto.createHash('sha1').update("some text").digest("hex")).toString('base64') );
// MzdhYTYzYzc3Mzk4ZDk1NDQ3MzI2MmUxYTAwNTdjMWU2MzJlZGE3Nw==
console.log( new Buffer(crypto.createHash('sha1').update("some text").digest("base64")).toString('base64') );
// TjZwangzT1kyVlJITW1MaG9BVjhIbU11Mm5jPQ==
```

---

```
<?php
echo base64_encode(sha1("some text"));
// MzdhYTYzYzc3Mzk4ZDk1NDQ3MzI2MmUxYTAwNTdjMWU2MzJlZGE3Nw==
echo base64_encode(sha1("some text", true)); // <-- how to reproduce it on the nodejs?
// N6pjx3OY2VRHMmLhoAV8HmMu2nc=
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
> crypto.createHash('sha1').update("some text").digest('base64')
'N6pjx3OY2VRHMmLhoAV8HmMu2nc='
```

Comment: GMT +2.0 04:50:36... Thanks!))